# Select based on WHERE-clause on multiple rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite table like this:

```
GroupID UserID
1       1
1       2
1       3
2       4
2       1
```

...and so on. Then, given a list of UserID, I would like to get a groupID that has all those userIDs and only those userIDs.

For example, in this table, given a list (1,2,3), the value returned should be 1. For the list (1,4) it should be 2. For the lists (1,2) or (3,4), nothing should be returned.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select GroupID 
from your_table 
where UserID in (1,2,3)
GROUP BY GroupID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

Comment: @user3586515 . . . Based on your response to my answer this doesn't work.  It would return the first group if the list were 2 and 3.

Comment: In this case, the last line would be HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 (2 is the length of given list)... so it should work anyway? Or am I missing something_

Comment: no, you are not missing anything.  This solution works as long as a user id can only be added to group once, with respect to that group.  the user can be added to a different group but as long as user id 1 for group 1 exists only once, then disco!

Answer (score 0):

You are a little unclear in the question.  Would "1" be returned if the list were 2 and 3?

This is an example of a set-within-sets subquery.  The most general and flexible approach is to use aggregation with a `having` clause:

```
select GroupId
from table t
group by GroupId
having sum(case when UserId = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when UserId = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when UserId = 3 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when UserId not in (1, 2, 3) then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Each clause counts the number of times that each user appears.  The `> 0` requires that each user appear at least once.

You might find it easier to express this as:

```
select GroupId
from table t
group by GroupId
having count(distinct case when UserId in (1, 2, 3) then UserId) = 3 and
       count(distinct UserId) = count(*);
```

However, you have to be sure that the "3" matches the number of elements in the `in` statement.

Comment: No, for the list (2,3) nothing should be returned. So, a selected group must contain only the users in the list. I think, the second solution should works, though; thanks!

Comment: @user3586515 . . . I modified the queries based on that clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a dependent subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable t1
WHERE UserID IN (1, 2, 3) 
  AND NOT EXISTS 
      (SELECT 1 
       FROM myTable t2 
       WHERE t2.GroupId = t1.GroupId 
         AND UserId NOT IN (1, 2, 3));
```

In plain english, you're selecting the records that contain the specified `UserId` values, and rejecting anything that doesn't contain exactly all three. This methods has the advantage of allowing an arbitrary number of elements in the `IN` clause without needing to know exactly how many you're passing in.